# not able to install device plugin in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to install device plugin by command line

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Folder is added into plugin directory. But im getting error. and not able to get features like device.cordova

```
Failed to install 'org.apache.cordova.device':Error: E:\Smargav\Projects\Done\na
tmobile\app\platforms\ios\cordova\version: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Amit S\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:818:12)
Error: E:\Smargav\Projects\Done\natmobile\app\platforms\ios\cordova\version: Com
mand failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Amit S\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:818:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Be sure to have the latest updates installed. Run `sudo npm update -g cordova` and update cordova first if not.
the Cordova Device Plugin will be installed with:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

Try it and let me know, if that fixed your problem!

**If nothing helps, try to create a new project**

1. `cd desktop`
2. `cordova create TestProject com.example.com Testproject`
3. `cd TestProject`
4. `cordova platform add ios`
5. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device`
6. `cordova build`

Comment: i'm using version 4.3.0. and i have cordova.

Comment: Yes. Everything is fine. But i'm working on android platform only. My project have ios and android platform. Here i have to add that plugin into android only. So that may be cause. How to add plugin to particular platform only

Comment: In new project, It is working. It may be because of several platforms

Comment: Remember that you can never build an iOS Project on another PC than a Mac

Comment: Yeah. Here my problem is not on build. It is in adding plugin

Comment: Then it probably was something with the iOS platform you had added. Funny how Android platform was overlooked and then I was told it isn't mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to be sure if:

1. Have you installed [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)?
2. Is the PATH of Ant and JDK and Android/iOS set correctly? To do so, edit your PATH variable:

`;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin`

3. Have you added a platform (iOS or Android) without any issues?

If all of it was done correctly and you still are facing an issue, try creating a new project and add platform(s), and see if there are any warnings in the process.

Comment: No word about android, no word about missing ant or sth with a wrong path.

Comment: Yes. Everything is fine. But i'm working on android platform only. My project have ios and android platform. Here i have to add that plugin into android only. So that may be cause. How to add plugin to particular platform onle

Comment: @Sithys, from my experience, the errors in NPM are sometimes werid, so I was being sure. @Mohaideen, you cannot add a plugin for a specific platform only. Could you try creating a new project, or try removing the iOS platform from the current one? `cordova platform remove ios` should do that.

Comment: You cann't add plugin platform specific. And if want  android only then don't add ios platform... some times its firwall issue also, may be some websites are bloacked..